# Extract everything after slash or backslash using Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am a newbie in regex and trying to figure out how I could split this string in Java:

My input string can be of one of the following forms:

```
String myStr = "%abc%\xyz\test.exe";
String myStr = "%abc%/xyz/test.exe";
String myStr = test.exe
```

I am trying to extract "test.exe" in every case.

I am not able to split the input string correctly as if I use the following:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myStr.split("[^\\/]+$")));
```

I get:

```
[%abc%/xyz/]
```

Which is part of the string I don't want. Any idea how I can get the delimiter itself in this case with Java string split?

Comment: Use `myStr = myStr.replaceFirst("^.*[/\\\\]", "");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace everything upto last `/` or `\` using `replaceFirst`:

```
String myStr = "%abc%\\xyz\\test.exe";
myStr = myStr.replaceFirst("^.*[/\\\\]", "");
//=> "test.exe"

myStr = "%abc%/xyz/test.exe";
myStr = myStr.replaceFirst("^.*[/\\\\]", "");
//=> "test.exe"

myStr = "test.exe";
myStr = myStr.replaceFirst("^.*[/\\\\]", "");
//=> "test.exe"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QcqAS8/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7+ you don't need regex.

Code:

```
String myStr = "%abc%\\xyz\\test.exe";
String myStr1 = "%abc%/xyz/test.exe";
String myStr2 = "test.exe";
System.out.println(Paths.get(myStr).getFileName().toString());
System.out.println(Paths.get(myStr1).getFileName().toString());
System.out.println(Paths.get(myStr2).getFileName().toString());
```

Output:

```
test.exe
test.exe
test.exe
```